# How to get a seed wallet in bitcoin-cli?

Tags: bitcoin-core, seed

how does one get a seed wallet in bitcoin_cli ?

I use a `bitcoin-cli sethdseed` command but get the error `:invalid private key`

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin core wallets are deterministic by default i.e. all private keys are derived from a seed. However you can make sure that your wallet is deterministic by running the [getwalletinfo](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/getwalletinfo/) command. In the response hdseedid  will only be set if it's an HD wallet.

Bitcoin core does not encode the seed as a mnemonic of english words. To create a backup of the wallet use the [backupwallet](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/backupwallet/) command.

Comment: HI If I want to change it, how do I do it and what do you mean by HD?
And how should I use SEEDID?

Comment: HD = hierarchical deterministic wallet i.e. a wallet where all address specific private keys are derived from a seed. i only mentioned seedid because it tells you whether your wallet is HD or not. If it's present you have an HD wallet. To change the seed you can use sethdseed: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/sethdseed/. However I don't recommend it.

Comment: Hi, I read that link was useful, but I got an error Private Key
and Can hdseed be used as a wallet recovery word?
For example I am now in a bitcoincor wallet 
I have 1 bitcoin unit and I also have hdseed

Comment: @nickburcart see the second paragraph in my answer above about how to backup your wallet. i suggest you take your follow up questions to bitcointalk's technical support subforum. this place is not for back and forth discussions.

Comment: Hi, I read that link was useful, but I got an error Private Key
and Can hdseed be used as a wallet recovery word?
For example I am now in a bitcoincor wallet 
I have 1 bitcoin unit and I also have hdseed
Can I get 1 bitcoin in another full node bitcoincor using this sethdseed one?